# How to get the item count in tkinter treeview?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I inserted several items to the [treeview](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-treeview).
Can I lookup the overall number of items which are stored in the treeview ?
Or even better: Can I iterate over **all** items like `for child in tree:...` ?

*Python 3.X Tkinter 8.6*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The treeview has a `get_children` method which can get all children for an item. It's a simple matter of calling that method on the root, and then calling it on every item that has children.

This method is documented in the page that you linked to in your question.

Here's a quick example:

```
def get_all_children(tree, item=""):
    children = tree.get_children(item)
    for child in children:
        children += get_all_children(tree, child)
    return children
```

On my box it took about 15ms to find all items in a tree that had 11,000 items

Comment: Yes, but then you have to do it recursively. I don't like that.

Comment: Isn't it a bit of overkill for only getting the count of items ?

Comment: @mr.wolle: your question ended with _"...even better: Can I iterate over all items...". `get_children` is how you iterate over all of the items.  And once you know how to iterate over all the items, you can easily compute the count.

Comment: @mr.wolle you don't necessarily have to do it recursively, and how is that overkill?

Comment: Okay, if their is no better solution I will do it this way :(

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I think recursion is the easier way. Right ?

Comment: @mr.wolle it will probably be easier to write and understand, and recursion limits are unlikely to be a problem for any sensible treeview. But you don't *have* to use it, if you don't want to.

Answer (score 5):

`len(tree.get_children())` works for my `ttk.Treeview` in 8.6

Comment: len(tree.get_children()) only works with a very simple Treeview object - no subordinate items under the top level items.  The get_all_children function shown earlier counts them all.